# finding of k which solves specific task in parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let us suppose we have following  parallelogram
[image]

Task is following : find $k$ for which  in vector addition form

$AB+BO=k*AC$

interesting task, first of all, we have following equation from  vector point of view

$AB+BC=AC$
$AD+DC=AC$

$BD=AD-AB$

from where, $AB=BD+AD$ , so if we insert, we will get

$BD+AD+BC=AC$

but how to continue? generally   intersection point is centroid  and is should be $1/2$, but how  to get it from the equation? thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to *prove* that the diagonals of a parallelogram meet at their respective midpoints, or just use that to derive $k = 1/2$?

Comment: no  no i dont need it, what i need is to find $k$

Comment: Then $AB+BO=AO=AC/2$.

Comment: that what i was thinking  from the begining, but i  wasnconfusing about one thing,  AB  is going  upward, BO is going down,  for example AB+BC  right, AB is going up, BC is going right,so that was i was confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

[image]

From triangle law on $\triangle AOB$ and $\triangle AOD$, we have

$$k AC + lDB = AB \\
k AC - (1-l) DB = AD$$

So, adding the two,

$$(2k-1)AC + (2l-1)DB = 0$$

and since $AC, DB \neq 0$,

$$k = l = \dfrac{1}{2}$$